# NiFi: Production usage without web UI

Tags: apache-nifi

Here are some commonly suggested approaches for using NiFi without web UI, along with their respective limitations. Is there a better way to use NiFi in Production without using web UI while still being able to makes changes to data flow design dynamically?

- **REST API approach**: The REST APIs can be used only with previous knowledge of the `ID` of the components and do not work with `NAME` of the components.
- **MiNiFi approach**: The MiNiFi is more focused on collection of data at the source. Additionally, the MiNiFi configuration too is tied to the previous knowledge of `ID` vs `NAME` of the components.

Answer (score 3):

A typical NiFi dataflow goes through the following environment lifecycle.

1. You build your flow in a development NiFi setup. You run it, test it, debug it, fix it.
2. Once you are sure that the flow runs as expected, promote it to the QA setup and perform similar actions.
3. Finally when your flow passes QA, promote it to the production setup. Have stringent policies set so that no one expect the support team or the admin have access to make the changes to the flow(s).

In other words, you don't have to *rely* on the REST API (event the UI changes are done through internal REST API calls) or disable Web UI, if you follow the proper dev-qa-prod promotion.

On a side note, you can leverage `NiFi Registry` to do the dev-qa-prod lifecycle.